# XSS via img tag, redundant semicolons?

Tags: javascript, html, security, xss

I was looking over the WebGoat exercises, and for one question they ask that you create a JavaScript alert using an img tag.

Their solution is thus:

```
<img src=x onerror=;;alert('XSS') />
```

Looking at their solution, I wonder why two (as opposed to just one) semicolns are necessary before the actual alert?

Comment: None are necessary. My best guess (and being no expert, that's not very much) is that they think that a strangely formed piece of javascript code might throw off some detection methods. If this is the case I doubt that it fools anybody.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed the semicolons aren't necessary i just tested the same tag w/o the semicolons on FF5 and Chrome latest, they both send the alerts with this

```
<img src=x onerror=;;alert('XSS') />
<img src=x onerror=alert('XSS') />
<img src="x" onerror="alert('XSS')" />
```

i think they are trying to stop the onerror event in the first semicolon, then output the bogus code out of the event in the alert

i tried this

```
<img src=x onerror=alert('eventfire');;alert('XSS') />
```

and it encloses both alerts inside the event, so its not running the second alert outside the event scope.

answer? seems to be doing the same thing w/o the semicolons (maybe there for old browsers that parse the html poorly and execute the alert outside the scope of the event???)